# The task is to insert an asterisk (*) between every pair of even digits in the given input, and return it as a string

Tags: python, loops, printing, anaconda

What is wrong with my code? How to print my output in a single line?
Everything is perfect with this code except when I use print() it returns the output individually and when I use the 'return' the output is only the first sentence.

```
def asterisc_it(n):
    x=str(n)
    for i in range(len(x)-1):
         if int(x[i])%2==0 and int(x[i+1])%2==0:
            print( x[:i+1]+'*'+x[i+1:] )

asterisc_it(9682135)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think you really done it but the problem is that you are printing the result instead of saving the change, so I've edited your code

```
def asterisc_it(n):
    x=str(n)
    final = ''
    for i in range(len(x)-1):
        if int(x[i])%2==0 and int(x[i+1])%2==0:
            final += x[i]+'*'
        else:
            final += x[i]
    final += x[len(x)-1]
    print(final)
```

Notice few things:
1. I've added a `final` string so we wont change the length of `x`
2. Inside the loop I've replaced `print( x[:i+1]+'*'+x[i+1:] )` with `final = x[:i+1]+'*'` so the change made to the string will be saved
3. I've added else statement that will add to the final in case it is doesn't answer to the if statement.
4. **after** the loop, add the last digit to the `final` string
4. lastly add `print(x)`, so I would get 1 result with all the changes

Comment: Thanks, but when I run a list like [1, 4, 64, 68, 67, 23, 1] the code fails. How to get the result for a list also? Also when I give input like '2222' or '0000', the output comes as 2*2*22 and 0*0*00 instead of 2*2*2*2 and 0*0*0*0 respectively. Please help me out for this.

Comment: @BalabhadraChand Your comment made me notice that I have a major error in the code, Please, notice the new changes, this would fix the issues you have with 2222 and 0000 and even 24682468

Comment: Ya I got it, but when I put the input as a strinf (e.g.-[1, 4, 64] ). It shows the error, then I tried with the below code by converting the list to string first, but it shows the error as "STR object is not callable"   def asterisc_it(n):
    x = ' '.join(map(str, n)) 
    final = ''
    for i in range(len(x)-1):
        if int(x[i])%2==0 and int(x[i+1])%2==0:
            final += x[i]+'*'
        else:
            final += x[i]
    final += x[len(x)-1]
    print(final)

Comment: Please add it to your original question, I really can't understand what you are trying to do with the array input and what comes first